# How to define a map class in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm new to Java. I’ve the following map defined:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> data_validation = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

data_validation.put("ACF:T_RECORDS", 66);
data_validation.put("ADF:V_RECORDS", 88);

Set set = data_validation.entrySet();
Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
    String file_type_name = mentry.getKey().toString().split(":")[0];
    String column_name = mentry.getKey().toString().split(":")[1];
    Integer records = Integer.parseInt(mentry.getValue().toString());
}
```

I'm wondering how to refactor the above code. How can I create a Java Class for this? Any suggestion?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @Berger Was just about to ask the same. This question is very unclear.

Comment: Yes, sorry, still not very familiar with Java terminology.

Comment: And why do you want to create a class? You don't just create classes for no reason. Classes are meant to represent a certain behavior.

Comment: @chenlayton If you just want to wrap this code, put it in a function.

Comment: I did put it in a function. I'm basically like to know if there is better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a map, create a class with three fields:

1. String fileTypeName
2. String columnName
3. int records

Then, put the data into a `List`, filling in those fields instead of doing this string parsing / manipulation.

```
List<MyClass> dataValidation = new ArrayList<>();
dataValidation.add(new MyClass("ACF", "T_RECORDS", 66));
dataValidation.add(new MyClass("ADF", "V_RECORDS", 88));
```

Where `MyClass` is something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String fileTypeName;
    private String columnName;
    private int records;

    public MyClass(String fileTypeName, String columnName, int records) {
        this.fileTypeName = fileTypeName;
        this.columnName = columnName;
        this.records = records;
    }

    // Add getters, setters.
}
```